# How to get the id from one of the elements of the row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

In the next table I'm trying to get the id from 'idIntervaloHorario' in order to pass it by the hidden field (like idCitas, which is called with callback_column, that's why is so easy getting idCitas). This table has been built with the join of two tables (intervaloshorarios and citas), so, how can I get the id of any 'idIntervaloHorario' which is related with a specific 'cita'?

**Join tables**

[image: Join Tables]

**Output**

[image: output]

**Database**

[image: database]

**Controller (this is not the full controller code)**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

$crud->where('entregas.idCitas =', $idCarga); 
       $query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo();
  
        if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCarga);
            $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $query);
        }

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
```

**Model function(trying to get max id)**

```
public function get_idintervalo() {
        $qry = $this->db->select('MAX(idIntervaloHorario)')
                ->from('intervaloshorarios')
                ->get();
        if ($qry->num_rows() > 0){
            return $qry->row_array();
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: Can post tables structures with expected output?

Comment: Done. As you can see, the idIntervaloHorario has been inserted manually, so i need to get that id from first table (with query?). The database has been updated too.